# PHP Unable to execute created command, but exec() and system() work properly

Tags: php

I'm facing a problem where PHP is able to execute CMD commands on Windows properly, but when I create a custom command to run, nothing works.

**Logic:**
I want to "cd" into a directory and then run python script that will scrape data from the web and save it in csv. Python script works fine.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    $keyword = $_POST['singleSearchTerm'];
    $filename = $_POST['singleFilename'];
    $settings = file('settings.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $conda_path = $settings[0];
    $working_env = $settings[1];
    $script = "scrape.py";
    $url = "https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=";
    $current_dir = getcwd();

    // cd into path
    $cd_path = "cd " . $conda_path . "&& ";

    // activate env
    $activate_env = "activate " . $working_env . " && cd ";

    // run python script
    $pyCommand = $current_dir . "\\ps\\ " . " && python -W ignore ". $script . " --url " . $url . $keyword . " --fname " . $filename;

    // full command
    $full_command = $cd_path . $activate_env . $pyCommand;

    echo $full_command;

    // test - works fine
    exec("start notepad.exe");

    // doesn't do anything
    exec($full_command);

    // doesnt do anything
    system($full_command)
}
```

**Generated Command:**
After the above PHP is loaded, the following command is generated:

```
cd C:\Users\da74\Anaconda3\Scripts && activate scrape && cd C:\MAMP\htdocs\pinscraper\ps\ && python -W ignore scrape.py --url https://www.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=old --fname dat.csv
```

**Issue:**
When the above command is pasted in CMD, it runs. But when it's passed using exec() or system() in PHP, it doesn't run.

**Tested:**
Have tested:

```
exec("start notepad.exe");
```

and it opens a notepad window. I don't know what's the problem. Is it hidden spaces? or something else?

Any help is appreciated.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I got alternative method to run it using NodeJS.

It anyone looking for the same problem, found out that PHP leaves unusual spaces after and before '&&' and sometimes a line break for no reason.

For this, I installed nodejs. Then made the PHP to save each var in a settings file line by line and let nodejs form a command to run using 'process' and exec. It works perfectly and only needs few lines of code.